# IE8 & IE9 gradients using -ms-filter cover the element

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, gradient

When applying:

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=1,startColorstr=#FFFFFF,endColorstr=#000000)";
```

to a DIV, the gradient behaves as if its an element covering the div and therefore mouse cursor no longer changes nor does mousemove events occur on the div.  The only part of the div still responding is the border.

I've googled and cried and put the cows to bed but all to no avail.  It displays perfectly but I need to have the containing div respond to mouse events and I've no more hair to tear out.

A happy day indeed it will be when we no longer care about the poor sods using IE8/9

Comment: Let's say IE9 it's ok, but for IE8 I advise you to use what the browser has, don't make it render gradients, border-radius etc. You're just lower the responsive time of the browsers. My advice is not to use filter: at all, since it will make the browser just render slower. When you get to IE try to keep it as simple as you can, for now IE8 is almost dead. IE11 will be lunched soon and then, let's say our job will get easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're right; that's exactly how a gradient filter works.

I think your only recourse here is to either use a traditional, pre-rendered gradient image as a CSS background, or apply the filter to another element that's positioned directly behind the div (or a `:before` pseudo-element possibly? I'm not sure how gradients work with generated boxes).

Comment: Well at least now I know.  The new css3 linear-gradient works a treat in chrome and FF and I was hoping IE's proprietary version wouldn't suck too much.  Anyway, if there is no way to make it work the same then yeah the old div behind a div hack will have to be brought out and dusted off again.  I'm so tempted sometimes to just say "fck it" to all the IE8/9 users and code ignore them but there's too many of them out there so have to resort to all this crap.  Anyway, you've answered the question - that's the way it is - I would like to mark your answer as the correct one but not sure yet how.